# select option tag in three column

Tags: javascript, html, css

The below select tag is in one row i need that in three column with select option tag:

http://jsfiddle.net/QZa7R/

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Terestrial">
    <option value="Car">Car</option>
    <option value="Tank">Tank</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Air">
    <option value="Airplain">Airplain</option>
    <option value="Helicopter">Helicopter</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Water">
    <option value="Ship">Ship</option>
    <option value="Submarine">Submarine</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: i have an image of the above question but i cant post because i have less reputation.

Comment: u can add image url in the comment

Comment: http://imgur.com/smrzjyX

Answer (score 1):

According to the Image you provided,  what you need to achieve is not possible by just using `<select>` tag and `CSS`. Either you'll have to use some sort of plugin, or create a `<div>` and put your content in it accordingly.

You can also take a look at this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aq5LS/) but my suggestion is you should create a `<div>` and put your content in it

ps. I am not an author of that fiddle i found it while browsing around

Comment: nice fiddle. effective and only mildly amusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The image you pointed to is using js to trigger a different HTML element (a div, perhaps) containing sub elements, perhaps `li`s with `<a>`s or the like.

There may be a select underneath (yay accessibility) but it's hidden when you want something like that displayed. You'd then need to use JS to either update your actual select element and trigger the submit on your form or to post the form data to the server asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

looking for  three column Please Try it

```
  <style>
    select optgroup.column3 {
        display: -moz-groupbox;
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        background:red;
    }
    </style>

<select>
  <optgroup label="Terestrial" class="column3">
    <option value="Car">Car</option>
    <option value="Tank">Tank</option>
  </optgroup>

  <optgroup label="Air" class="column3">
    <option value="Airplain">Airplain</option>
    <option value="Helicopter">Helicopter</option>
  </optgroup>

  <optgroup label="Water" class="column3">
    <option value="Ship">Ship</option>
    <option value="Submarine">Submarine</option>

</fieldset>
</select>
```